# Navigating from one xaml to another in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Despite the fact that I am totally a fresh to WPF, I need to write a code, in which after I click a button, the application should open another xaml. After searching on the web, I did in in the following way:

1.I created two xaml files, namely 'Window1.xaml' and 'Window2.xaml'.

2.In my 'App.xaml' file, I let:

```
<Application x:Class="DiagramDesigner.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
```

3.Then in my 'Window1.xaml', I created a button:

```
<Button Name="Button" Click="Button_Click_1" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter_1" IsDefault="True"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    Start
</Button>
```

4.In my "Windwo1.xaml.cs" file, I created these two functions:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
    }

    private void Button_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

5.Then for opening "Window2.xaml" after clicking the button, I changed to:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        NavigationService service = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        service.Navigate(new Uri("Window2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

But this gives me error, saying the `service` is null, and the program crashed. I didn't figure out any way to solve this. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var window = new Window2();
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

You should also read the documentation on `NavigationService` class and its methods to avoid further confusion on what this class does. Here is a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives an error, saying: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()'.

Answer (score 2):

NavigationService could not be used in classic WPF desktop application that use the `Window` class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx.

You could navigate between `Page` class instances but not between `Window` class instances.

You have to show and hide it manually using such techniques as shown in [WPF. How hide/show main window from another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814170/wpf-how-hide-show-main-window-from-another-window)