# How to proper navigate from one xaml page to another from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

I am building a windows phone application in which at same point i am trying to navigate from one xaml page to another when a button is clicked.

To do this i tried two different ways, each of them seems to be incorrect.

First way, i added this code in the button click event handler

```
    private void About_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/About.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

This way is not working all the time, at some point when i am trying to navigate from one page to another a strange "System.AccessViolationException" is thrown already in the debug version of my application.

Second way, i added this code in the button click event handler:

```
    private void About_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        About about = new About();
        this.Content = about;
    }
```

where About is a xaml page.

In this second way the navigation seems to work fine in the debug version of my application. But once i published a beta version of my application and download it from the windows phone store, pressing on the button which is doing the navigation is crashing the application. And what is most strange is that if i am deploying the application even in a release version from the VS 2013 to my phone, is working fine...

Any ideas why is this happening and how to proper implement this page to page navigation ?

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate() is the proper way, I am using it all the time in several WP8 applications

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigating from one xaml to another in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285132/navigating-from-one-xaml-to-another-in-wpf)

Comment: The solution from the proposed duplicate is not working here, already from the begining after the xaml page is instantiated there is no "ShowDialog" method for the "about" instance.

Comment: Ok, maybe [take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=navigate+to+another+xaml) and we can pick out a better example to use as the possible duplicate? Point is, it's a common question that's discussed multiple places both here and around the net. :)

Comment: It could be a common thing, but what the hell navigating from one page to another is a simple operation, it should exists a recomended way in this "fancy" wpf

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Page Navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259534/windows-phone-8-1-page-navigation)